# vb.net overload choice algorithm seems to contradict the docs

Tags: vb.net, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

I'm writing a compiler (just for fun lol) and I've decided to base the overload resolution logic on vb.net.

According to the MSDN docs

[Overload Resolution (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx)

So my interpretation of this is, the compiler will reject functions that require a narrowing of a data type

and

only select functions that require the minimum amount of widening

until only one candidate function remains, or fail (ambiguous) if more than one function remains in the candidate list.  Ok, that all makes total sense.  I'm assuming it prevents narrowing to prevent data loss.

But the following VB program compiles fine. I was expecting a compiler time error due to the narrowing rule. It compiles with no errors or warnings but will always crash at runtime. I can't see how the program will ever run correctly but the compiler doesn't complain.

```
Module VBModule

  Sub z(a as long, b as single)
    Console.WriteLine("long a, single b")
  End Sub

  Sub z(a as short, b as double)
    Console.WriteLine("short a, double b")
  End Sub

  Sub z(a as integer, b as double)
    Console.WriteLine("integer a, double b")
  End Sub

  Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!")
    dim p as long
    dim q as double

    p = 1
    q = 1

    ' all the available versions of z() will result in data loss, so I 
    ' was expecting a compile time error for this call.
    call z(p, q)
  End Sub

End Module
```

The equivalent Java program (java uses similar overload resolution rules, i.e. no narrowing allowed) does complain at compile time, which is what I expected from vb.

```java
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void z(long a, float b) {
    System.out.println("long, float");
  }

  public static void z(short a, double b) {
    System.out.println("short, double");
  }

  public static void z(int a, double b) {
    System.out.println("int, double");
  }

  public static void main(String []args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    // this fails to compile in both java and vb.net
    /*{
      short p;
      short q;

      p = 1;
      q = 1;

      z(p, q);
    }*/

    // this fails to compiler in Java, which is what I expected.  
    // It compiles OK in Vb net but bombs with a runtime error,
    // not sure why the vb compiler doesn't complain at compiler 
    // time!!!!!
    {
      long p;
      double q;

      p = 1;
      q = 1;

      z(p, q);
    }  
  }
}
```

Any of you vb.net users have any advice? maybe a compiler switch I'm missing or something.  Is it possible to force the compiler to only use compile time resolution instead of runtime resolution?  It seems the compiler cant find an appropriate overload at compile time, so it leaves it till runtime.

I'm using online compilers for these tests.

[Visual Basic Online Compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_vb.net_online.php)

[Java Online Compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php)

Comment: what if you set `Option Strict On`?

Comment: @T.S. is on  the money.  Your code does indeed fail to compile with `Option Strict On`.  Any self-respecting VB developer really should have that set in the IDE options, thus it will be `On` by default in every new project and you can then turn it `Off` explicitly in only those specific code files that need it, which will be few to none for most developers.

Comment: Thanks, I do get a compiler warning now.  In terms of the narrowing rule the ms docs state "This is true whether the type checking switch (Option Strict Statement) is On or Off."

Comment: "I'm using online compilers for these tests." - this is likely the source of the problem.  The output window shows "mono main.exe" that implies the website is using the mono compiler.  There is likely a bug in that compiler.  I have not been able to reproduce your observed behavior using Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2013 or 2015 nor the SharpDevelop IDE (I don't know if they use their own compiler or not).

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I don't use VB much at all these days not since VB3 lol,  Can you tell me if Visual Studio has a command line compiler for VB, that would help me write some automated test code rather than using the web based compiler.

Comment: for vbc (VB compiler), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/380cz5k4.aspx - also see Roslyn (on which latest compilers of VS are based if I'm not mistaken) at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: Great question, surprised there are not more upvotes. The only advice not given so far is debugging into the .Net Framework. I'm sure you know this, but to enable .NET Framework source debugging, Tools Menu > Options > Debugging section > set Enable .NET Framework source stepping and then click Symbols to set the symbols cache.
Since .Net core is open source you may like to compare Core to .Net Framework and also vs Mono - doing that should yield the answer and the different resolutions offered.